# What is the event to handle row select in Kendo

Tags: kendo-grid, telerik-grid

I have a Kendo Grid in which I want to add an event handler for row select. In the Telerik Grid, the code is

```
ClientEvents(events => events.OnRowSelect(""))
```

However, I can not find OnRowSelect in Events in Kendo. How to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you still have to respond to the change event.  See the Telerik help for the Grid event change:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-change

Comment: The problem is that if use change event, when create a new record or edit an existing record, it will execute the change event too, which causes problem in edit or create record. Any thought on this?